# TFLite / mobilenet_v3: Are you using an older TFlite binary with a new model?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to implement Mobilenet_V3 to a program that was successfully working and still does work with Mobilenet_V2. This is on a Raspberry Pi 4 4gb with a Google Coral USB accelerator.

On the deployment of the program I encounter an error that says the following:

> ERROR: Op builtin_code out of range: 117. Are you using old TFLite
>   binary with newer model? ERROR: Registration failed.
>
> Error in interpreter initialization.

I tried to redownload and compile the TFLite binary based on the instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi

but upon doing this I encountered an error that said something like

///
tensorflow build essential 117 not upgraded
///

Are the 117 numbers merely a coincidence? Not sure how to proceed on updating my TFLite binary but any help would be appreciated.